# Powershell import external DLL

Tags: powershell, dll

I have a very simple question.  How do i import DLL's into my powershell script.  I am using power shell 3.0.  I've looked at a few articles and they all seem to be very confusing.  I would just like a simple example.

I have the DLL complied and in a folder on my C drive.

What command do i need to use at the top of my script load the DLL's?  Please don't reference me to another article a simple example would be appreciated.

Comment: Already asked and answered with a simple example

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question works for 3.0 as well.

Comment: Last question for you.  After you loaded the dll's is there any IDE that will allow you to use the . notation.  For example, I use "." and it shows me all the methods and properties to that function I am using from the DLL?

Comment: Visual Studio should as long as you add a reference to the DLL in the project.